# Stationary measure of a not-explosive continuous time Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-calculus, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $X_n$ be a non-explosive continuous time Markov chain with a stationary measure. Is it possible that its embedded discrete time Markov chain does not have a stationary measure?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(t)$ be a continuous-time Markov chain on the nonnegative integers with generator matrix
$$
Q_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1,& i\geqslant 0,j=i+1\\
1,& i\geqslant 1, j=0\\
-1,& i=j=0\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $X(t)$ is non-explosive as $\sup_{i,j\in S} Q_{ij}=1<\infty$. Consider the balance equations $$\sum_{i\in S,j\notin S}Q_{ij}= \sum_{i\in S,j\notin S}Q_{ji} $$
for the subsets $S=\{0\},\{0,1\},\ldots$ of the state space:
$$
\pi_n = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \pi_i,\ i\geqslant 0.\tag1
$$
From $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \pi_i=1$ and setting $n=0$ in $(1)$ we find that $\pi_0=\frac12$, and iterating yields the recurrence $\pi_n = \frac12\pi_{n-1}$. It follows that $X(t)$ has the stationary distribution $\pi_n = \frac12^{n+1}$.

The embedded chain has transition matrix
$$
P_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac12,& j=0\\
\frac12,& i\geqslant 0, j=i+1\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\tau=\inf\{n>0: X_n=0 \mid X_0=0\}$. Then $$\mathbb E[\tau] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(\tau>n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac12=\infty,$$ so the embedded chain is transient.